# Reporting Service in maintenance mode

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I'm trying to put RS in maintenance mode. I've tried to put an app_offline.htm (usual for IIS maintenance mode), but get en RS error message instead of the message set into app_offline.htm.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, `app_offline.htm` works fine.